# Adjetivo sinônimo de "mente aberta"

Tags: palavra-para-ideia, adjetivos

Existe algum adjetivo na lingua portuguesa que tenha a mesma semântica de “mente aberta”, mas que não seja uma locução adverbial?

Gostaria de denominar assim uma pessoa que, frente a um contra-argumento bem colocado, decida racionalmente mudar de opinião, sem hesitar ou se envergonhar.

Eu não procuro adjetivos com conotação negativa tais como “volátil”. E seria bom se fosse algo formal, então “desapegado” também não funciona.

Sim, eu procurei na web, bastante, mas os dicionários online em português parecem ainda um tanto fracos, então conto com o conhecimento de vocês!

Comment: Queres um adjetivo que funcione em qualquer contexto, ou mesmo sem contexto? Exemplo: poder dizer-se «ele é ______» em vez de «ele tem mente aberta»? Se quiseres um adjetivo para usar numa frase em particular, podias indicá-la (ou uma parecida), com um espaço em branco (_______) para o adjetivo. Poderão haver adjetivos que funcionem no contexto em que o queres usar, mas não em todos os contextos. Pior ainda, poderá não existir nenhum adjetivo que funcione em todos os contextos.

Comment: @Jacinto eu procuro algo compreensível fora de uma frase completa. Seria legal usar de forma "atômica", ou seja, idealmente uma palavra compreensível por si só. O contexto seria unicamente o descrito acima =)

Comment: O único adjetivo que encontrei por conta própria foi _contemporizador_, mas não estou seguro de seu uso (não sei o que significa!), e não sei se existem outros melhores!

Comment: [Contemporizador](http://www.aulete.com.br/contemporizador) tem que ver com *conciliador*, não serve. Não sei se existirá o adjetivo que tu queres, embora os gregos antigos devessem ter um ;) Das propostas até agora, *razoável* parece-me a melhor: combina intelecto para apreciar o argumento e temperamento para o aceitar, em vez de ficar na sua por teimosia; *João, face à argumentação sólida, sendo uma pessoa razoável, mudou de opinião*. Mas se dissesses, *meu vizinho é razoável*, eu pensaria mais uma pessoa que se lhe pedires para fazer pouco barulho depois da meia noite, compreende e aceita.

Comment: Ou simplesmente que não é má pessoa. Mas o mesmo vizinho poderia não estar minimamente interessado em escutar os teus argumentos que o aquecimento global é real. *Mente aberta* tem também essa conotação de *mente curiosa*, que não transparece em *meu vizinho é razoável*. Por isso é que eu perguntei se tens uma frase: uma adjetivo pode funcionar numa frase e não funcionar noutra.

Comment: @Jacinto você mirou precisamente na direção que vinha refletindo sobre _razoável_... A pessoa razoável não parece fazer tanto esforço em refletir, curiosamente, me parece ter uma correlação alta com "_sensato_" - a pessoa com bom senso. Eu acredito que isso talvez derive de [significados (Michaelis)](http://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno/portugues/index.php?lingua=portugues-portugues&palavra=razo%E1vel) tais como 2 Sensato, moderado. 3 Aceitável, suficiente. 4 Acima de medíocre..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na minha opinião, a palavra que melhor se encaixa é “razoável”, mas “humilde”, “recetivo” e “sensato” também se aproximam bastante.

Comment: Júlio Reis, eu concordo com você, depois de refletir muito sobre as possibilidades apresentadas, "_razoável_" parece ser a melhor escolha, até porque só percebi agora, a raiz vem de _razão_, ou seja, uma pessoa racional. Também não havia percebido que é o par direto do francês _raisonnable_ e inglês _reasonable_... Contudo, _razoável_  ainda tem uma conotação de 'um pouco melhor que mediano', o que não é tão positivo como eu esperava. Parece "fazer pouco caso" do esforço empregado para convencer ou mudar de opinião... o que você acha?

Comment: @DBS Penso que _razoável_, se usado relativamente a uma pessoa, tem uma conotação bastante positiva, de alguém que aceita e usa a razão (capacidade de raciocínio crítico). Se usado relativamente a um objeto, já terá um significado subjetivo de “bonzinho”, “melhor do que a média”.

Comment: Pessoal, obrigado por todas as sugestões. Acredito que, como foi argumentado pelo Jacinto e Júlio Reis, _razoável_ tenha a semântica mais próxima da que procuro. Não fiquei 100% satisfeito, pelo que foi dialogado aqui, mas _razoavelmente_ satisfeito ;) Já é o suficiente para fechar a questão.

Answer (score 6):

Tentei procurar mente aberta pelo termo em inglês *open-minded* em alguns dicionários para averiguar se encontrava um adjetivo adequado, então vi o termo *approachable* que pode ser entendido como **receptivo** em português.

Segundo o [aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/receptivo) **receptivo** é um **adjetivo**:

> 1. Propenso a ou capaz de receber, aceitar bem estímulos, ou opiniões,
>      sugestões.

Seguindo sua descrição:

> pessoa que, frente a um contra-argumento bem colocado, decida
>   racionalmente mudar de opinião, sem hesitar ou se envergonhar.

Esta pessoa pode ser **sensata** (**adjetivo** também, segundo o [aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/sensato)):

> 1. Que tem ou revela bom senso (jovem sensato; atitude sensata)
> 2. Que age com coerência e discrição.

Comment: Eu pensei em _approchable_ também :) _Receptivo_ é bom, pelo Aulete encaixa bem com _"open minded"_ ... +1

Answer (score 3):

Um indivíduo que é (ou tem) a mente aberta, é livre de preconceitos, capaz de ouvir opiniões contrárias às suas e avaliar se as aceita ou não. Para tanto, ele deve ser [**"despreconceituoso"**](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/despreconceituoso) e [**"racional"**](http://www.significados.com.br/racional/)

> - despreconceituoso - "que não tem ou não demonstra preconceitos."
> - racional -"aquele que pensa, raciocina, que age segundo a razão"

Comment: Sim, eu concordo. A pessoa é desprendida de preconceitos, ela é uma pessoa "_não-axiomática_" +1.

Comment: *Racional* se enquadra bem a este termo +1.

Answer (score 2):

No meu entendimento, ter uma mente aberta significa não apenas ser capaz de aceitar bem contra-argumentos, mas também de respeitar opiniões ou atitudes diferentes — mesmo que não concorde com elas.

A partir disso, eis algumas sugestões.

### tolerante

Segundo o [Aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/tolerante):

> Que releva e aceita as falhas alheias; INDULGENTE
>
> Que aceita e respeita ideias ou comportamentos distintos dos seus

### indulgente

Segundo o [Aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/indulgente):

> Que perdoa, desculpa ou releva facilmente (diz-se de pessoa com tendência a perdoar)

E o Houaiss:

> que ou aquele que tem disposição para desculpar ou perdoar; clemente, tolerante
>
> que ou aquele que se mostra favoravelmente disposto na apreciação de trabalhos ou atos de outrem

### compreensivo

[Aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/compreensivo):

> Que compreende, que tem entendimento
>
> Que tem ou demonstra compreensão

### flexível

[Aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/flex%C3%ADvel):

> Que se mostra compreensivo, tolerante

**Receptivo**, como mencionado por outros, também é uma boa palavra.

Comment: dessas a que se encaixa melhor é flexível

Comment: Concordo André, _flexível_ e _receptivo_. Os demais tem mais relação com _mente aberta_ mesmo, que usei mais como exemplo ("um pontapé inicial"). Obg Argumentum

Answer (score 0):

Bom, também estava procurando esse adjetivo, e entre os sinônimos de "mente aberta", o que mais me satisfez foi "receptivo"
Significa quando uma pessoa é capaz de aceitar opiniões, sugestões contrárias à sua com facilidade, sem se sentir desvalorizado

Comment: Olá e boas-vindas ao Portuguese SE! A palavra que você sugere já foi sugerida em outras repostas, por exemplo [esta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/a/3306/2764) — considere se sua postagem é mais um comentário do que um resposta de fato (podemos fazer a conversão) e não deixe de votar 'up' nas respostas (e perguntas) que você considera boas contribuições.